# trajeto linear em linguagem c

Tags: c

Ola, sou Lísias e gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar nessa tarefa tão difícil para finalizar minha biblioteca.

Eu fiz um motor de jogos, e nele já consegui implementar todas as funções básicas para um uso primário. Fazendo a criação de jogos simples através dela.

Mas estou desenvolvendo um rpg, e resolvi fazer com que os personagens atirem a longa distância. Porém, para que isso aconteça, tenho que fazer com que o objeto a ser atirado sempre corra em linha reta.

Criei uma função que faz com que todos os objetos se movam na tela, mas ela não funciona de uma maneira linear. O que posso modificar nessa função para que ela me proporcione isso?

```c
PLACE_CALL STATUS PLACE_TYPE place_user_route(CHAINED * user, BP32 x, BP32 y) {
    if (user && USER_C(user->it)->object && bit_is_on(USER_C(user->it)->object->status, OBJECT_VISIBLE)) {
        OBJECT_SET * U = USER_C(user->it)->object;
        if (U->x_route == x && U->y_route == y) {
            obj_where_stop_all(U);
            return (On);
        }
        //printf("xs %f ys %f\n",object->x_speed,object->y_speed);
        if (U->x_route == x) {
            if (U->y_route > y) {
                U->y_route += -U->y_speed;
                U->where_stop_but(U, NORTH);
                if (U->y_route < y) {
                    U->y_route = y;
                    U->where_stop(U);
                    return (On);
                }
            }
            if (U->y_route < y) {
                U->y_route += U->y_speed;
                U->where_stop_but(U, SOUTH);
                if (U->y_route > y) {
                    U->where_stop(U);
                    U->y_route = y;
                    return (On);
                }
            }
            return (Off);
        }
        if (U->y_route == y) {
            if (U->x_route > x) {
                U->x_route += -U->x_speed;
                U->where_stop_but(U, WEST);
                if (U->x_route < x) {
                    U->where_stop(U);
                    U->x_route = x;
                    return (On);
                }
            }
            if (U->x_route < x) {
                U->x_route += U->x_speed;
                U->where_stop_but(U, EAST);
                if (U->x_route > x) {
                    U->where_stop(U);
                    U->x_route = x;
                    return (On);
                }
            }

            return (Off);
        }
        if (U->x_route > x) {
            U->x_route += -U->x_speed;
            if (U->x_route < x)U->x_route = x;
            if (U->y_route > y) {
                U->y_route += -U->y_speed;
                U->where_stop_but_and(U, NORTH, WEST);
                if (U->y_route < y)U->y_route = y;
            }
            if (U->y_route < y) {
                U->where_stop_but_and(U, SOUTH, WEST);
                U->y_route += U->y_speed;
            }
        }
        if (U->x_route < x) {
            U->x_route += U->x_speed;
            if (U->x_route > x)U->x_route = x;
            if (U->y_route < y) {
                U->y_route += U->y_speed;
                U->where_stop_but_and(U, SOUTH, EAST);
                if (U->y_route > y)U->y_route = y;
            }
            if (U->y_route > y) {
                U->y_route += -U->y_speed;
                U->where_stop_but_and(U, NORTH, EAST);
                if (U->y_route < y)U->y_route = y;
            }
        }
    }
    return (Off);
}
```

essa é a minha tentativa pra mudar essa função:

```c
PLACE_CALL void straight_line(CHAINED * user, BP32 x, BP32 y) {
    if (user) {
        OBJECT_SET * U = USER_C(user->it)->object;
        BP32 x_distancy = (x > U->x_route) ? round(x - U->x_route) : round(U->x_route - x);
        BP32 y_distancy = (y > U->y_route) ? round(y - U->y_route) : round(U->y_route - y);
        if (x_distancy && y_distancy) {
            if (x_distancy != y_distancy) {
                //if (U->x_speed_old != U->x_speed)U->x_speed_old = U->x_speed;
                //if (U->y_speed_old != U->y_speed)U->y_speed_old = U->y_speed;
                U->x_speed = (x_distancy / y_distancy) * U->resistance;
                U->y_speed = (y_distancy / x_distancy) * U->resistance;
            } else {
                if (U->x_speed != U->y_speed) {
                    //if (U->x_speed_old != U->x_speed)U->x_speed_old = U->x_speed;
                    //if (U->y_speed_old != U->y_speed)U->y_speed_old = U->y_speed;
                    U->x_speed = (U->x_speed > U->y_speed) ? U->x_speed : U->y_speed;
                    U->y_speed = (U->y_speed > U->x_speed) ? U->y_speed : U->x_speed;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (!x_distancy && !y_distancy) {
                //U->x_speed = U->x_speed_old;
                //U->y_speed = U->y_speed_old;
                U->x_route = x;
                U->y_route = y;
            }
            if (x_distancy && !y_distancy) {
                U->x_speed = (x_distancy / (x_distancy * U->resistance));
                //U->y_speed = U->y_speed_old;
                U->y_route = y;
            }
            if (y_distancy && !x_distancy) {
                U->y_speed = (y_distancy / (y_distancy * U->resistance));
                //U->x_speed = U->x_speed_old;
                U->x_route = x;
            }
            if (U->x_speed < 1 && U->y_speed < 1) {
                //U->x_speed = U->x_speed_old;
                //U->y_speed = U->y_speed_old;
                U->x_route = x;
                U->y_route = y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Isso é o que fá fiz com o motor:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuLi_lB6c4Y&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Quando você escreve "mas ela não funciona de uma maneira linear" o que significa? Geometricamente o sprite está  saltando entre os frames,  o movimento não está suave ou a trajetória é um arco?

Comment: Quando eu digo isso quero dizer que se a distancia entre uma das coordenadas cartesianas for mais distante que a outra ele vai chegar mais rápido no destino mais próximo. Por exemplo, se a distância x for menor que a y ele chegará primeiro no ponto x, causando assimetria de movimento. Eu desejo que esse movimento seja simétrico, como por exemplo uma bala que percorre a mesma direção em linha reta. Eu já vi uma função chamada bresenha, mas não consegui adapta-la totalmente em meu projeto.

Comment: Procure por Algorítimo de Bresenham. Que é uma técnica usada para desenhar uma trajetória reta em planos cujo os vetores base da ordenada ou da abcissa são continuamente discretos.

Comment: Foi como eu disse, eu já havia estudado esse algoritmo, mas por ele conter um laço for, eu não consigo adapta-lo no laço principal do jogo.

Comment: Mas no seu caso, game engine, ao invés de usar um `laço for` você o divide o algorítimo em passos e usa o `frame rate ideal` para saber quantos passos interpolar por segundo e a cada frame que desenhar você usa o `frame rate real` para saber quantos os passos deve pular e qual passo usar para atualizar a posição do projétil.

Comment: sim, a ideia é essa, mas pra colocar isso em pratica que estou tendo problemas